# how to access variable in xslt?

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

could you please tell me how to access variable in xslt ? .I make variable in `js` .I want to print it's value .So I assign the variable value in xsl:variable
when I try to print variable value it gives me `string` instead of evaluating 
here is my code
http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LWb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
        <script>
             console.log('starte');
             var start = 5; 
             '<xsl:variable name="start">{start}</xsl:variable>'
            console.log('<xsl:value-of select="$start"/>')

        </script>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```

**Expected output** :: 5
any update

Comment: I made a comment on your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498064/why-value-of-not-working-in-xslt-in-loop) which is relevant here. XSLT can't access javascript variables, because by the time the HTML and Javascript is created the XSLT (and XML) is long gone and is not accessible. XSLT is used to generate HTML (and javascript), but it is not used in the processing of that HTML. You should really start off by trying to write the HTML you want manually, putting aside XSLT until you know exactly what you want your HTML and javascript to look like.

Comment: could you pls answer ths Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505285/how-to-change-the-tag-name-in-xslt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i can suggest you do like this:

demo - https://jsfiddle.net/skyr9999/behf2h7t/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
        <script>
             console.log('starte');
             var start = 5; 
             document.write('<xsl:variable name="start">'+start+'</xsl:variable>');
            console.log("<xsl:value-of select='"+start+"'/>")

        </script>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```